# Error when trying to run a static app nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a wampp server and I would like to run my nuxt application on it...

`router` is in `hash` mode

I ran `npm run build`, it generates the files, but when trying to open, it redirects to c:

What am I doing wrong?

https://63177131e5cb6100ae26a9c0--enchanting-pika-27cd8b.netlify.app/

[image: NUXTAPP]

import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

```js
export default {
  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  ssr: true,
  target: 'static',
  head: {
    titleTemplate: '%s - fprod',
    title: 'fprod',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/persistedState.client.js'
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/vuetify
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
  ],

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
  axios: {
    // Workaround to avoid enforcing hard-coded localhost:3000: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/issues/308
    baseURL: '/',
  },

  // Vuetify module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-vuetify
  vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    theme: {
      dark: true,
      themes: {
        dark: {
          primary: colors.blue.darken2,
          accent: colors.grey.darken3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3
        }
      }
    }
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
  },

  route: {
    mode: 'hash'
  },

  router: {
    middleware: 'stats'
  }
}
```

Comment: `npm run build` is for an SSR build. If you want SSG, you need to use `npm run generate` and to have `ssr: true` + `target: 'static'`. Also, please do not post images of code but actual (relevant) code as text. If you still have some issues, sharing your `nuxt.config.js` could be helpful, on top of providing us a [repro] or a public github repo. Some debugging could also be done by trying to host the app on Netlify.

Comment: Looks like the build on Netlify is working great.

Comment: @kissu when u try to access the pgae, console out: DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method.... but when u try to access a router like /registo, it run perfect... what is wrong?

Comment: This error comes from the fact that you're running a client side code on server. `appendChild` does not exist on a node environment.

Comment: how to solve it?

Comment: Depends of your code.

Comment: @kissu it looks like solved now... but why is not working on my wamp server? https://prnt.sc/ENJmPkBfSYfe

Comment: All the failed responses are not looking like it's actually solved to me haha. Mind sharing your repo + how to access the app?